#  Can I make the parent page's label on the navigational menu not clickable in Wordpress using TwentyTen theme?

Tags: navigation, wordpress-theming, hierarchy

I want to create a 2 level hierarchy using one of the pages.

I have a 5 page web site and page2 happens to have page2.1 and page 2.2

And as a result, in the navigation, (using TwentyTen theme), when I hover the mouse over the page2 label, I've been able to get the page2.1 and 2.2 dropdowns to appear automatically.

The problem is that Wordpress and TwentyTen generate a clickable page2 label. I want the page2 label to act only as a navigational header for the 2.1 and 2.2 nav items as there is no content for page2.

How do I make it unclickable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom menu item with no link or use a redirect plugin like Simple 301 Redirect to just direct that page to 2.1 if someone clicks on it.